# Asynchronous Processor and Synchronous Writer in spring batch

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-integration

I am writing a spring batch program to generate some Json and write this to a target table.To improve performance, I have used AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter, but there are issues in AsyncItemWriter since some of the logics like incrementing version of the Json based on previous entries in target table, when multiple threads process. Is there any other way to implement processor alone as asynchronous and writer as synchronous in spring batch

Thanks in advance